# ReactJS - Conditional execution only works if state var is empty string, breaks if null or false

Tags: javascript, reactjs

## I'm having a recurring bizarre issue with conditional rendering in React.

When I try to evaluate a state variable for truthy/falsy, **it only functions properly if I have that variable set to an empty string** -- null or false will break the entire component with the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of null
at traverse (bundle.js:42660)
at forEachSingleChild (bundle.js:8941)
at traverseAllChildrenImpl (bundle.js:9934)
at traverseAllChildrenImpl (bundle.js:9950)
at traverseAllChildren (bundle.js:10029)
at Object.forEachChildren [as forEach] (bundle.js:8961)
at traverse (bundle.js:42669)
at forEachSingleChild (bundle.js:8941)
at traverseAllChildrenImpl (bundle.js:9934)
at traverseAllChildren (bundle.js:10029)
```

[image]
Here's a very stripped down snippet of the code triggering it, obviously most of the function's actual HTML has been removed as it's irrelevant:

```js
export class MyComponentName extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      itemsLoaded: false,
    };
  }
  
  render() {
    if (this.enableTranslations && this.props.location.query.id) {
      return (
        this.editCategoryTranslatedView()
      );
    } else if (this.props.location.query.id) {
      return(
        this.editCategoryUntranslatedView()
      );
    }
    else {
      return(
        this.addCategoryView()
      );
    }
  }
  
  
 editCategoryTranslatedView() {
  return (
   {
    this.state.itemsLoaded
    ?
    <SOME HTML HERE>
    :
    this.sectionLoading()
   }
  )
 }
```

## Edit: It appears it might a React package for Tabs on a page causing the  issue

```
import {Tabs, TabContent, TabLink} from 'react-tabs-redux';
```

It's used in this manner inside the returning function:

```html
<Tabs>
  <TabLink to="tab1">English</TabLink>
  <TabLink to="tab2">Translations</TabLink>
  <TabContent for="tab1">
 {
    this.state.itemsLoaded
    ?
    <SOME HTML HERE>
    :
    this.sectionLoading()
 }
 </TabContent>
 <TabContent for="tab2">
  //etc etc
 </TabContent>
</Tabs>
```

```js
var Tabs = function (_Component) {
     _inherits(Tabs, _Component);

     function Tabs() {
         _classCallCheck(this, Tabs);

         var _this = _possibleConstructorReturn(this, (Tabs.__proto__ || Object.getPrototypeOf(Tabs)).call(this));

         _this.state = {
             selectedTab: null
         };

         _this.handleSelect = _this.handleSelect.bind(_this);
         return _this;
     }

     _createClass(Tabs, [{
         key: 'handleSelect',
         value: function handleSelect(tab) {
             this.setState({
                 selectedTab: tab
             });
         }
     }, {
         key: 'findDefault',
         value: function findDefault(children) {
             if (this.defaultTab) {
                 return this.defaultTab;
             }

             var firstLink = void 0;
             var firstDefaultLink = void 0;

             var traverse = function traverse(child) {
                 if (!child.props || firstDefaultLink) {
                     return;
                 }

                 if (child.props.to) {
                     firstLink = firstLink || child.props.to;
                     firstDefaultLink = firstDefaultLink || child.props.default && child.props.to;
                 }

                 _react2.default.Children.forEach(child.props.children, traverse);
             };

             _react2.default.Children.forEach(children, traverse);

             this.defaultTab = firstDefaultLink || firstLink;
             return this.defaultTab;
         }
     }
```

Comment: r u facing issue in `editCategoryTranslatedView` function ??

Answer (score 0):

Apply the function call with this context. e.g   'this.editCategoryUntranslatedView.apply(this)' and try.

Comment: I tried binding context through .bind and the lamba arrows (=>)

It appears it might be code inside of a React package for generating tabs on a page